# SPSiteDataquery returning null datatable

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I need to query all the subsites of a site I m in. I have list called Country which is 2-3 sub level of site my webpart is rendering. My code till now is this..
Country is custom list,DT1 is coming out to be null. I don't know where I m getting wrong , any idea on this?

```
           SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

           SPSiteDataQuery qry = new SPSiteDataQuery();
            qry.Lists = "<Lists BaseType='1' />";

            qry.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>USA</Value></Contains></Where>";

            qry.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Currency'/>";

             qry.Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection' />";

           DataTable DT1= web.GetSiteData(qry);
```

Comment: I have had similar problem when the required viewfields were not found in all the queried lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify tyat all lists with BaseType='1' has field with internal name Currency or else you will get null as a result.

Comment: I have changed it to <FieldRef Name='Currency' Nullable='TRUE'/> but still result is the same

Comment: Actually BaseType is O for generic list and by doing Nullable='TRUE' , I m able to solve my problem. Thanks anyways...

Comment: Then answer your question and accept it if you have a solution.